# ionic 3/angular/angularfire2 upgrade eventually producing error - No provider for AngularFireDatabaseModule

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angularfire, angularfire2

I am using `ionic 3` and I just updated `angular` to `5.0`, and `angularfire2` to `5.0`. I had to get through some errors, and I have arrived at this one and I am not sure what is going on, as I think everything I am doing is right. The error is:

> Uncaught (in promise: Error: StaticInjectorError[AngularFireDatabaseModule]:
>   StaticInjectorError[AngularFireDatabaseModule]: NullinjectorError: No
>   provider for AngularFireDatabaseModule!

In my app.module.ts file I have:

```
...

import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database'

...

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    NgCalendarModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, //Here it is in imports

    ...
```

The error happens when I try to go to a certain page in my app...one with some angularfire2 requests. I updated these requests to `angularfire2 5.0` code so it shouldn't be giving me an error. I used `angularfire2/database-deprecated` so that I can run the app without having to change all the requests beforehand. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Looks like Angular is trying to inject `AngularFireDatabaseModule`. Is it passed as an argument to a component/service constructor somewhere in your code? Shouldn't a service be injected instead?

Comment: thats the thing...i havent injected it anywhere...I only inject `AngularFireDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

Add import :-

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Then in providers array add **AngularFireDatabase**:

```
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AngularFireDatabase,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ]
```